# Flask and pdf viewer (pdf.js)

Tags: javascript, html, flask, pdf.js

I am trying to solve the following problem: I need to display a .pdf document on a web page using pdf.js plug-in. When I embed the following line in a Flask app:

```
iframe src = "/path/to/test.pdf" width = "30%" height = "30%"></iframe>
```

it returns 404 error, but a pdf file is displayed in pdf.js when I use the same line in a regular  .html file.

Comment: Next time show a bit more from your code ;)

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. Since I am new to Flask and web development, I didn't know that I have to keep all files in a Flask environment. I thought that a full path to pdf file would be enough. Everything woks fine after moving the file to a proper folder.

Comment: Thanks for posting, please be specific indicate which folder for other readers and also accept your answer. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by keeping pdf in static folder,It worked :)

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to comment due to low reputation, but to expand upon "chemist"'s answer,

```html
<embed src="/static/labels.pdf#page=1&zoom=200" alt="Label Preview" type="application/pdf" frameBorder="0" scrolling="auto" height="500px" width="100%">
```